# Django Queryset Values of Children and Parent

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am looking for a way to retrieve a parent field during a query of the the children records.  At this time I have the following example model.

```
class Record(models.Model):
    event_title=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    event_description=models.CharField(max_length=4000)
 
class SecondTable(models.Model):
    event_code=models.ForeignKey(Record, default=0, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wasfun=models.BoolField(default=True)
```

When I view the values of the queryset and select_related below, the values from the parent don't seem to be included (i.e. event_description).  However, the `.query` property shows all the fields being selected.

```
SecondTable.objects.all().select_related("event_code").values()
```

Is there a way to see all values from the joined tables?  Sorry for a newbie question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think not in only one line, but you can try with next:

```py
values_second_table =  [s.name for s in SecondTable._meta.fields]
values_first_table =  ['event_code__{}'.format(r.name) for r in Record._meta.fields]
my_values = values_second_table + values_first_table
SecondTable.objects.all().select_related("event_code").values(*my_values)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to pull the values from the query but the list you created has all the fields as you thought it would.  It doesn't recognize any column names from the Record model, but has only the field names from the SecondTable.

Comment: Yes, sorry Tyler, I was to change the name of "record" field (you called event_code)

Comment: Still not bringing the columns into the .values()...Maybe it's something with that command?